# Vertically center Ionic icons with the text around them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

Im using Bootstrap 3 and [Ion Icons](http://ionicons.com/cheatsheet.html).

Given the below HTML with all the default Bootstrap CSS, the plus icon next to "New Url" is significantly smaller than the text like this:

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/RxguB/261/)

[image]

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New URL<i class="icon ion-ios-plus-empty"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
```

---

I'd like the icon to be the same size as the text, however, when I try to do so by adding the below CSS, the sizes match

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/RxguB/259/)

```
.navbar-default i{
    font-size:26px;
}
```

### [image]

Adding `margin-top: -8px;` to the `li` makes the text line up with the other `lis` but the icon and its text still are not aligned.

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/RxguB/262/)

[image]

---

I also tried adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the icon but the icon is then lower than the text:

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/RxguB/265/)

### [image]

Is there a better way that I can use to make the icons the same size as the text and also be aligned with the text?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're encountering here, is that the rendering block of the icon is not just the icon itself. The rendering block of the icon is higher, than the actual icon and contains some "white space". See the screen below, indicating the rendering block for the icons :before element.

[image]

There's nothing really you can do about it, since Ion is responsible for generating the webfont files for you and therefore leaving you with the "white space" above and below the icon.

You can see this on the Ion website, too, if you inspect any icons :before block on the overview page.

If you can, you can switch to another webfont, where the :before blocks fit to the actual part of the icons (without white space around it). Or you can generate your own webfont using SVG files (e.g. by using [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/)).

Comment: Seeing that you were correct about the space being added by the actual icon framework I dropped the icon into an absolutely positioned span and was able to get what I needed from there, Thanks for the help +1

Answer (score 3):

You can try by the exact value of `vertical-align`. Below the example is.

```
    vertical-align: -4px;
```

Comment: That does align the icon to the text, +1, Unfortunately, this approach still leaves the containing `li` out of alignment with its neighbors, in which case I'd prefer to have the absolutely positioned comtainer span

Comment: Yes, I think that is perfect. I also use that.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `vertical-align: middle` in order to align the text with the icon.

```
i.icon.ion-ios-plus-empty{
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/263/)

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, but even there, the icon is lower than the text, it's still not truely centered

Comment: @DelightedD0D Have you checked the demo ? its centered !!

Comment: Please check the image I just added in my update, it does not seem to be cetered

Answer (score 0):

After @Regaddi showed me that the space above and below the icon are artifacts of the actual ionic icon itself, and cant be manipulated with CSS, I corrected this by placing the icon in an absolutely positioned span allowing me to move it around till it was just right regardless of that space, like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
    <li data-toggle=".url-panel-header"><a href="#">New URL<span class="ion-fix"><i class="icon ion-ios-plus-empty"></i></span></a></li>
</ul>


.navbar-default i{
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left:4px;
  
}

.ion-fix{
 position:relative;
  
}
.ion-fix i{
 position:absolute;
 top:-5px;  
}
```

---

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/RxguB/266/)

[image]